# Extract date field from text in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to extract a date field from a text in Oracle SQL

Below is an example of 2 rows of the data. The data does not always match in length or content, but the date field is always in MM-DD-YYYY format

```
Name: JONES            01-01-2001      Marital St: SI
Name: GEORGE SMITH            01-02-1999
```

I tried using REGEXP_SUBSTR to only retrieve the date but I was unsuccessful. Is there any way the date can be extracted from this type of data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried REGEXP_SUBSTR with this pattern?

```
\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}
```

Should work.

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMN,'\d{2}-\d(2)-\d{4}' ) worked for some records, but not others, even when the content and length was the same.

Comment: even when the content and length was the same? that seems like very strange behavior?

Comment: note that I made a typo and corrected the pattern from: `\d{2}-\d(2)-\d{4}` to `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}`. That doesn't work either?

Comment: Working now, after I updated to \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}, thanks for the help!